# spark how to join datasets

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'd like to rewrite this pseudo sql code to spark sql or java

```
select a, collect_list(b)
from Authors a left join Books b
group by a
```

but it seems in sql I can operate only with columns and don't how to deal with it. Besides have a few questions:

- Is it somehow preferred to use sql over java (scala is not an option)? Eventually I'll use spark with kafka.
- Should I use `Dataset<Author>` or `Dataset<Row>` is ok?

Edit: To be more precise about the goal. I've a few datasets like Persons, Phones, Addresses etc. Actually there will be kafka streams. Relation is optional one-to-many I need to join these datasets by person.id to collect all the corresponding data (phones, addresses) and save everything to db possibly using hibernate

Comment: What is your purpose? You join two tables but there isn't a join key. What are you doing exactly?

Comment: https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-sql-dataframe-join/ ?